# R regex beginning of line ^ in data frame values

Tags: regex, r

Given:

```
    test <- data.frame(Speed=c("2 Mbps", "10 Mbps"))
```

Why does this regex match the following values:

```
    grepl("[0-9]*Mbps$", test[,"Speed"], ignore.case=TRUE)
```

but fails to match those below:

```
    grepl("^[0-9]*Mbps$", test[,"Speed"], ignore.case=TRUE)
```

The `^` (beginning of line/string) character is causing the issue, but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^[0-9]*Mbps$` regex looks for a number at the beginning and then for `Mbps` at the end. And since there are spaces in-between, there is no match. To match the strings, use `^[0-9]*\\s*Mbps$`.

```
test <- data.frame(Speed=c("2 Mbps", "10 Mbps"))
grepl("^[0-9]*\\s*Mbps$", test[,"Speed"], ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Output of the [demo program](http://ideone.com/XP6dkD):

```
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

`[0-9]*Mbps$` matches just `Mbps` at the end of each item because the `[0-9]*` can match an empty string due to the `*` quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

Because a space is missing in the regex;

**`"^[0-9]* Mbps$"` or `"^[0-9]*\\s*Mbps$"` would match the inputs**.

---

`"[0-9]*Mbps$"` matches (not necessarily from the beginning of the string) "zero occurences of digit-characters, followed by 'Mbps' and end of string".

`"^[0-9]*Mbps$"` doesn't match the inputs, because it requires the input to start with zero-or-more digits, then 'Mbps' (no space!), then end of string.

Answer (score 2):

The second version is basically saying that the only characters that can precede the "MBPS" or "mbps" or "Mbps" (if there are any)  are digits. Take a look at the results from an expanded dataframe with more possibilities:

```
> test <- data.frame(Speed=c("2 Mbps", "10 Mbps", "123Mbps", " Mbps", "aMbps", "Mbps"))
> grepl("^[0-9]*Mbps$", test[,"Speed"], ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> grepl("[0-9]*Mbps$", test[,"Speed"], ignore.case=TRUE)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The "trick" or "gotcha" here is that `grepl("[0-9]*Mbps$", ...)` really is no different than `grepl("Mbps$", ...)`. It's going to match a whole bunch of character strings that you probably don't want.